# What is this error? System.Net.InternalException in Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, httpwebrequest

We are getting a really rare error during HTTP requests:

```
System.Net.InternalException: System error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse(Object responseOrException)
at System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32 bytesRead, WebExceptionStatus errorStatus)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Any idea about what's the cause? Or shall we just ignore it?

Comment: I'd answer this for you, but I don't want my code being used for...evil.

Comment: Nothing major, just destroying the world :)

Comment: Get a system.net tracelog for your application. See instructions at http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html. What does the actual exception.Message say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to the async version of it, but that's very likely a dropped connection.

Comment: Although we handle all exceptions, are we supposed handle this exception differently? I noticed that async usage of HTTP can cause exceptions thrown in random places.

Comment: I wouldn't bother threating those exceptions differently. Note that when you aren't using the sync version a client disconnecting will also cause an exception anywhere response is being accessed.