# Deadly exception, how to catch? System.Net.InternalException: System error

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

```
System.Net.InternalException: System error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckWriteSideResponseProcessing()
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult retur
nResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteCallDone(ConnectStream stream, ConnectionRe
turnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean abort
ing)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeSta
te)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders_Part2()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteHeadersCallback(WebExceptionStatus errorSta
tus, ConnectStream stream, Boolean async)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr u
serToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32
 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

This was caught by the unhandled exception handler. It only occurs occasionally, but with disastrous results. Any ideas how to actually catch this one chaps?

**UPDATE**

It has now become apparent that this only appears to happen when the CPU is under exceptionally high load.

Comment: @Andrew really? why? do you have the answer?

Comment: Which of my questions should I accept answers on, which answer should I select, and why?

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been wondering what all those numbers and ticks are all over the place. I plussed one on both your comments so hopefully that will give you a bit more recognition.

Comment: Can you post some code to show in which context you are getting the exception - that might help to determine how you could catch it? Or does it just randomly bubble up "out of nowhere"?

Comment: Yes it comes out of nowhere, after doing thousands of successful async http requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this exception is thrown on an I/O completion thread basically without any intervention from you then I would be inclined to open a ticket with [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/). Reasoning: You start an async I/O operation which throws an exception presumably due to a dropped connection all by it's own on the thread pool - which you can't catch. That means there is a the possibility that a dropped connection during an async operation takes down your application and you can't do anything about it. Sounds like a bug in the framework to me.

Temporary workaround could be to place a `<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>` in the `<runtime>` section of your app config. This will revert to the .NET 1.0/1.1 behaviour where exceptions thrown on another thread than the main thread will not take down the application. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx

Comment: Agreed. Additionally, I'd recommend downloading the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) and using the adplus utility in crash mode (`adplus -crash -pn process_name.exe`) in order to get a memory dump that will help MS diagnose the problem.

Comment: That is a very useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

We had this same issue and were able to get assistance from Microsoft support on this. For us this was caused by a race condition in the winsock api caused by us disabling the Nagle algorithm.  You might want to check out my blog post if you find yourself in the same situation: [ASP.NET Serialization Exception Crash, winsock and Nagle Algorithm](http://www.computercabal.com/2011/11/aspnet-serialization-exception-crash.html).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are having a dropped connection.  This will be especially true if you are using Async calls.  Any time you try to access an object when the connection has been dropped, you will get an error like this.  Here is a SO article that has a bit more about it:

[What is this error? System.Net.InternalException in Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933346/what-is-this-error-system-net-internalexception-in-net-httpwebrequest-setandorpr)

Comment: Yes. I agree, but I do not know how to catch this Exception (other than in the unhandled exception handler, by which time its too late) since it is thrown on the IOCompletion thread.

Comment: @Tom - If you cannot catch the error itself when it is thrown (have you tried catching all exceptions on your code to see if it truly happens outside your control?), you might try checking to see if the connection is dropped before using the connection information. That might take a lot of extra work in your code, but it is the only viable option I see beyond trapping the exception.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds a bit.. nebulous.. not sure quite what you mean.

Comment: @Tom - :-)  That is because it is.  I'm not sure where in your code this exception is occurring.  In fact, there may be more than one place that can trigger this exception.  You will first have to find these places and see if you can catch the exception.  Start by trying a generic catch on all exceptions (`catch (Exception ex)`).  If you can catch it, deal with it.  If you cannot, try preventing the error from occurring by doing a check before performing the operation that causes the error.  See if you can cut it off from happening before it causes the problem.

Comment: I am catching all exceptions in my code as far as I know, the trouble is this happens on a io completion thread.. The best I've been able to come up with is to restart the process.

Comment: @Tom - In that case, try to get ahead of the error by figuring out what is tripping the error and doing a connectivity check first.

Comment: a connectivity check eh? do you mean as in 'is-the-internet-there?'  .. unfortunately not quite that simple I fear.